# I'm leaking memory and can't figure out why

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I'm currently writing a function that creates a tree (just to get comfortable with the C syntax I've learned so far). It works just fine, however, valgrind is yelling at me for leaking memory. I don't know where my code is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Global variables
const int SIZEOFTREE = 5;
const int INDENT = 4;
int counter = 0;

// Defines node of tree structure
typedef struct tree {
    int value;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
} tree;

// Prototypes
tree *create_symmetric_tree(int size);
void print_tree(tree *ptr, int generations);
void free_tree(tree *ptr);


int main(void) {
    tree *root = create_symmetric_tree(SIZEOFTREE);
    print_tree(root, SIZEOFTREE);
    free_tree(root);
}


// Creates a symmetric tree
tree *create_symmetric_tree(int size) {
    // Base case
    if (size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for node of tree
    tree *x = malloc(sizeof(tree));
    if (x == 0) {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Define value
    x->value = counter;
    counter++;

    // Create subtrees
    x->left = create_symmetric_tree(size - 1);
    x->right = create_symmetric_tree(size - 1);

    // Success
    return x;
}

// Prints a tree on the screen
void print_tree(tree *ptr, int generations) {
    // Base case
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // Printf the current generation
    for (int i = 0; i < (SIZEOFTREE - generations) * INDENT; i++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%i\n", ptr->value);

    // Printf left and right subtree
    print_tree(ptr->left, generations - 1);
    print_tree(ptr->right, generations - 1);

    // Success
    return;
}

// Frees the memory of the tree pointed to
void free_tree(tree *ptr) {
    // Base case
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // Free left and right subtree
    free_tree(ptr->left);
    free_tree(ptr->right);

    // Free the node itself
    free(ptr);

    // Success
    return;
}
```

This is the complete code. It worked perfectly, except valgrind didn't like it:

```
==10140== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10140==    definitely lost: 96 bytes in 4 blocks
==10140==    indirectly lost: 576 bytes in 24 blocks
==10140==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10140==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10140==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

After changing it to `if (x == NULL) {return NULL;}` valgrind told me no memory leaks are possible, but that line should only have been run if the allocation didn't work so I don't understand how I lost that many bytes.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including how the functions are called.

Comment: You are returning `1` as a `tree*` value?

Comment: It looks alright to me (apart from return 1 but that would only be a problem if the allocation failed). Valgrind should list all of the leaked blocks and where they were allocated. Are they the ones allocated in create_symmetric_tree? What size is the tree you create? Can you post the main() code just in case there's a silly mistake in it?

Comment: _"In main(void), I first create the tree and then almost directly free it again so I don't really understand where memory can have leaked"_: dont' describe your code but show it. [Edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: That turned out to be the problem, now returning NULL it doesn't anymore leak memory (also the if statement was supposed to be if x==NULL) - i still don't understand though how this line of code, that shouldn't even have been run, leaks memory?

Comment: If by "that" you mean returning `1`, then it does not make sense, and you probably have some other issues. You should have seen the error message printed if the code took that path.

Comment: Where is your `print_tree`? As said, you need to provide a complete [mre].

Comment: @anonymousclassjava no, returning `1` from `create_symmetric_tree` is wrong, but it's not the problem here, that code is never executed unless `malloc` returns NULLL, which is unlikely to happen. The rest of your codes looks correct to me. What happens if you call `create_symmetric_tree(0)` ? Do you also get leaks?

Comment: Calling create_symmetric_tree(0) works fine bc of the base cases in the functions

Comment: Are you sure the code you run is the code you compiled?